# Помогите понять диаграммы в "Сильные стороны" Дугласа Кроуфорда?

Tags: javascript

Начал читать книгу, но тут был сюрприз в виде диаграмм. Как их понять?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правильно ли нарисовал?

Comment: Представь что это дорога, по которой ты едешь. Слева направо. Где плавно, там свернуть можно, где острый угол - не стоит. Соттветственно свернув можно по кругу ездить, повторяя символ.

Comment: А вообще (строго имхо) я бы не парился с пониманием этих диаграм. Нужно понимать что это всего лишь визуализация (довольно неудачная на мой взгляд) нормального способа описания определенного типа грамматик: формы бэкуса-наура

Comment: @Утка, то есть, там где зеленая - можно, где красная - нет?http://joxi.ru/823LJbBiGEeOAO

Comment: Все, что относится к вопросу, должно быть **в самом вопросе**. Ссылки могут служить только _дополнением_.

Comment: _Правильно ли нарисовал?_ если про красные стрелки - то не везде